# Не читается русский текст из json-файла

Tags: python, json

При попытке прочтения из json-файла текста на русском языке выводится что-то непонятное. Как вместо этих закорючек получить нормальный текст?
Код:

```
with open('message.json') as file:
    msg = json.load(file)
    print(msg['message'])
```

Содержимое файла message.json:

```
{"message":  "привет"}
```

Вывод:

```
РїСЂРёРІРµС
```

Comment: `with open('message.json', encoding="utf-8") as file`

Comment: `$ echo 'РїСЂРёРІРµС‚' | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1251` → `привет`

Comment: Кодировка файла не соответствует кодировке, используемой при чтении. Попробуйте указать кодировку при открытии файла как указали выше - with open('message.json', encoding='utf-8') as file: